# How do I enable Exchange 2010 for IMAP (SSL and non SSL)?

Tags: ssl, exchange-2010, imap

I need to permit SSL and non non-ssl clients to use IMAP.

What is the command to enable IMAP in SSL and non-SSL mode?

Comment: Why would you use IMAP over Outlook Anywhere?

Comment: @KCotreau sometimes applications use IMAP to pick up mail. I've created a helpdesk system which does this for example.

Comment: OK, then I would ask is he doing this for an application, or for actual users. If for users, then see question #1. I think IMAP stinks.

Comment: This is for an application that doesn't support Outlook Anywhere.

Comment: OK, at least that makes more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this does it for you, but (first two are just in case):

```
Set-service msExchangeIMAP4 -startuptype automatic
Start-service msExchangeIMAP4
Set-CASMailbox -Identity "John Smith" -IMAPEnabled $true
```

Then one of the following depending on how secure you want it:

```
Set-ImapSettings -LoginType PlainTextLogin
Set-ImapSettings -LoginType PlainTextAuthentication
Set-ImapSettings -LoginType SecureLogin
```

You can also set security in the Management Console here: Server Configuration>Client Access>POP3 and IMAP>Properties>Authentication.